# Does CMake have an equivalent to a local.mk file?

Tags: makefile, cmake

I am in the process of converting a Makefile to CMake. We use several variables to configure a combination of build configurations.

These variables are things like:

```
OS := linux
CPU := amd64
BUILD_TYPE := dbg
```

Currently, we use a local.mk file to specify what values we would want to change these to if we were building for a different platform.

I know that I can pass these kind of values on the command line, but would prefer that I could modify a file and have that be used to decide the value of the before mentioned variables. Does CMake have an equivalent to a local.mk file that can change these values without modifying them inside the CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: There is an `include` for cmake.

Comment: CMake presets may be what you're after. It was introduced in 3.19. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.19/manual/cmake-presets.7.html

Answer (score -1):

The build type in particularly is handled by the [CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) variable. It is used to determine what flags to pass to the compiler for a build of that particular type. For example: when CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is `Debug`, it uses CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG. If it's `Release`, CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE is used.

When you're not doing cross-compilation CMake is clever enough to figure out the environment and what toolchain to use by itself.

I've no experience with cross-compilation using CMake, but using the [CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE.html) variable along with a file written with help from the [cmake-toolchains](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) documentation looks like the way to go. The "**Cross-compiling for Linux**" section is a good place to start with the example it provides.